# Manual trigger of delivery in Jenkins 2.0 for a successful build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline with build and test stages, and on success archiving the result:

```
node {
 try {
   stage('build') {
     sh 'make'
   }

   stage('test') {
     sh 'make test'
   }

   stage('archive') {
     archiveArtifacts artifacts: "build/"
   }
 } finally {
  junit "tests/*.xml"
}
```

I'd like **to trigger a 'deploy' stage manually** from the build page. For instance on the build page, there is a link to download the artifact. I'd like to have a custom button to trigger a 'deploy' action. This action would need to access to the archived artifact and call a web service.

I have tried with the 'input' step in my pipeline, but it's not satisfactory as the build doesn't appear as successful and is still active until I decide to process or abort. Since I'm using concurrentBuild=false, it's not a practical solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I'm still using the 'input' step, but it's pretty inconvenient,